# Angular pass template reference using ng-content

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular-template, angular2-ngcontent

I want to pass `ng-template` as `ng-content` nested inside child

app-component.html

```html
<app-parent>
  <ng-template appTemplateRetrieval>
    <div>this should be passed to grand child</div>
  </ng-template>
</app-parent>
```

---

parent-component.html

```html
<app-child>
  {{directivesTemplate}}
</app-child>
```

---

parent-component.ts

```js
 @ContentChild(TemplateRetrievalDirective, {static: false}) tplRetDir: TemplateRetrievalDirective;

  get directivesTemplate(): TemplateRef<any> {
    return this.tplRetDir && this.tplRetDir.template;
  }
```

directive

```js
export class TemplateRetrievalDirective {

  constructor(public template: TemplateRef<any>) { }

}
```

---

child-component.ts

```js
@ContentChild(TemplateRef, {static: true}) contentTpl: TemplateRef<any>;

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log(this.contentTpl) // logs to console: undefined
  }
```

stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cuipde

I expect `TemplateRef` to be passed two levels down: app-component > parent > child

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to pass data to more than 1 level up or down I suggest you to take a look to services and make the use of a subject or a behaviorSubject to pass the data between multiple components.

Comment: I was just wondering what implied that TemplateRef isn't being recognized by grand child